# trying to override alert, it works, but executes twice

Tags: javascript, prototype, overloading, alert, overriding

so, call me lazy but I'm trying to add a bit of syntactic sugar to Javascript's alert function. Here's the code:

```
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script>
window.nativeAlert = window.alert
window.alert = function() 
{
    window.nativeAlert(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(", ")+" window")
    return this
}
Array.prototype.alert = function()
{
    window.nativeAlert(this.toString()+" array")
    return this
}
Object.prototype.alert = function()
{
    window.nativeAlert(this.toString()+" object")
    return this
}
$(function()
{
    var features = $.getJSON("features.json")
    features.alert()
})
</script>
```

This seems to work, but is firing twice. Any idea why this happens? My gut says that it has something to do with overloading, but it works just fine (fires once) for arrays and for [window.]alert().

P.S. I know the JSON won't display properly yet, that's for later.

Comment: any reason for doing this? you can just say `alert(JSON.stringify(obj));`

Comment: The "alert()" function isn't really a JavaScript thing so much as a browser thing, to be perhaps needlessly pedantic :-)

Comment: Also it doesn't happen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7zbM/)

Comment: For some reason, looks like you're trying to reinvent `console.log`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a tricky one, it took a little bit of stepping through the call stack in a debugger to see what was going on.

What's happening is that `alert` is being added as a property to *every* object. That includes the object that is deserialized from the `features.json` file.

Once the `.getJSON` request is finished, jQuery parses the JSON string that is returned from the file. When jQuery finds a property of the object that is a function, it executes it. Since your `alert` is a property of the object, it calls it.

This is a good illustration of why it is a bad idea to add methods to `Object.prototype`. Anything that tries to iterate through the properties of an object will also encounter the custom prototype properties.